# Recursive Function to return File List - Android Java - File Manager

Tags: java, android

I want to return a file list from a function which loops through all the files/directories on SD card on android and which confirm the specific data type(mp3, mp4, png). But I cannot figure out when to return the values from the loop. Can anyone help me with this?

My code:

```
private Pattern patternVideo = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(mp4))$)");
private Pattern patternAudio = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(mp3))$)");
private Pattern patternImages = Pattern
        .compile("([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(png|jpeg|jpg))$)");

Matcher videoMatcher, audioMatcher, imageMatcher;

private ArrayList<String> videoFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> audioFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> imageFiles = new ArrayList<String>();


   private void buildFileList(File dirName) {
    if (dirName.isFile()) {
        // matcher = pattern.matcher(dirName.getName());
        // if (matcher.find())
        // fileNamesWithPaths.add(dirName.getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (dirName.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dirName.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                videoMatcher = patternVideo.matcher(file.getName());
                audioMatcher = patternAudio.matcher(file.getName());
                imageMatcher = patternImages.matcher(file.getName());
                if (videoMatcher.find()) {
                    videoFileNames.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else if (audioMatcher.find()) {
                    audioFileNames.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else if (imageMatcher.find()) {
                    imageFileNames.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                buildFileList(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't your method supposed to return something? why do you have it as void?

Comment: This is a earlier version of the code which populated the array lists with file names. Now I want it to return the file names upon calling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your return statement outside of the isDirectory() test:

```
  private ArrayList buildFileList(File dirName) {
       if (dirName.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dirName.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    videoMatcher = patternVideo.matcher(file.getName());
                    audioMatcher = patternAudio.matcher(file.getName());
                    imageMatcher = patternImages.matcher(file.getName());
                    if (videoMatcher.find()) {
                        videoFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else if (audioMatcher.find()) {
                        audioFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else if (imageMatcher.find()) {
                        imageFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    buildFileList(file);
                }
            }
        }
        //Combine your arrayLists here 
        return CombinedLists          //return the Combined Lists
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return anything; after the call the three *Files lists will have all the files you seek.

Edit: why won't you use the MediaStore provider?

Comment: I want to have it in a separate class and return the file list upon calling this method "buildFileList".

Comment: But you have three lists and can return only one object from a method. Solution: Encapsulate the three lists in an object - could be the same class that has the buildFileList method.

Comment: I figured that out. I will use the<br/>ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> finalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();<br/> to add all the lists into one. My main concern is when to return this finalList.

Comment: WTH - don't do that! Create a simple class and return that, will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stack will help you to avoid recursion:

```
private void buildFileList(File dirName) {
    Stack<File> stack = new Stack<File>();
    stack.add(dirName);

    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        File next = stack.pop();
        if (next.isFile()) {

            // do something...

        } else if (next.isDirectory()) {
            stack.addAll(Arrays.asList(next.listFiles()));
        }
    }
}
```